# Helvetia LBChange

Tags: dsl, pharo

What is the LBChange used for in Helvetia? I see that in every language box there is one #change: which returns a new LBChange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language change is used to encapsulate a local grammar adaption applied to the grammar of the host language. In our case a language extension is defined as a grammar fragment and a specification of how this fragment is composed with the grammar of the host language.

For a detailled explanation see "Chapter 5.2.1 Language Change" in my [PhD Thesis](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/phd/renggli-phd.pdf).